# Microsoft ReportViewer: Customize Y-Axis labels to match a specific format

Tags: c#, visual-studio, customization, reportviewer, yaxis

I would like to customize the Y axis labels of a graph plotted with Microsoft ReportViewer. 
What I want is to have a logic like the following:

```
If (value>1000000)
   return value/1000000 & "M"
else 
   return value
```

For example if the value of the label is 12000000 then the label value will be 12M, otherwise if the label value is 1200 the value will remain 1200.

I have tried to customize the numeric format to obtain this kind of behaviour tring something like:

```
= iif(value>1000000,value/1000000 'M',value)
```

(to help contextualize my question, i'm talking about this window=> https://dotnetblurb.files.wordpress.com/2012/05/3.jpg)

but, as expected, it didn't work.

Googling didn't help much as well, it seems like this kind of customization is just not possible. Or is it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue using both the expressions window and altering the graph's datasource content.

In the method filling the data source I added the logic converting big numbers into smaller numbers:

```
reportModel.MillionsSymbol = "";
if (reportModel.TotalValue > 1000000)
{
      reportModel.TotalValue /= 1000000;
      reportModel.MillionsSymbol = "M ";
}
```

I also added the new `MillionsSymbol` field to my data source and I change its content based on the TotalValue.

Then, I can use this new field in the dialog Vertical Axis Properties -> Number -> Category[custom]

```
="0.00" & Fields!MillionsSymbol.Value
```

[image: Expressions window]

The trick here is that I wrote an expression that is returning a string containing the characters mask needed by the function that is formatting the axis numbers' label. In this string I can put anything as long as it contains the mask (0.00, #.##,...).

This method allows me to concatenate a variable to the value that is going to appear as a label for every tick of the vertical axis of the graph. It doesn't allow me to work on that value, since I didn't find any way to get access to it. This is why I altered the values in the data source. In this way, though, I'm changing the value of the graph points and then conseguently the vertical axis ticks' values.

Final result:

[image]

*Image edited for clarity